# Golang LOAD DATA slows database/sql operations

Tags: mysql, go, load-data-infile

I'm loading multiple files into the database using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command combined with `database/sql` driver like this:

```
mysql.RegisterLocalFile(fileName)
_, err = dbConnection.Exec(loadDataCommand)
```

This works as expected after the load has finished I run some SELECT queries (I'm reusing `dbConnection` for those SELECT queries and all other queries) on newly loaded data and this is where the problem occurs. The above mentioned SELECT queries are unusually slow (due to high CPU usage).

While running LOAD DATA database CPU usage spikes which is expected but after the LOAD DATA finishes CPU usage should drop but it doesn't unless I close and reopen `dbConnection` CPU usage stays high.

This is how I'm "reseting" the database connection:

```
_ = dbConnection.Close()
dbConnection, err = sql.Open(databaseDriver, databaseUser+":"+databasePassword+"@tcp("+databaseAddress+":3306)/"+databaseName+"?multiStatements=true")
```

Why is this happening? The above code is running on a development database so there are no other connections to it.

Comment: Look at `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what's going on. Cutting the connection does not necessarily mean the server has nothing to do.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows only one SELECT query running

Comment: [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) may give more detail. Sometimes there's background processing that has to be done for InnoDB tables, index updates, etc. It can be normal for the server to need some time to settle down after importing a lot of data. The [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) may be able to help with queries like this. You may need to adjust server tuning parameters in order to get better performance.

Comment: Thanks, will post my question there and do some investigation with MySQL Workbench.